# Display 2 labels and inputs on the same line

Tags: html

Here's some sample code

```
<label for="input1">input1</label>
<input id="input1" name="input1" type="text" required>
<label for="input2">input2</label>
<input id="input2" name="input2" type="date">
```

Currently, it displays like this:

`Label` `Label` `Input` `Input`

I want it do do this:

`Label` `Input` `Label` `Input`

Any ideas? Do I need to provide more code?

CSS

```
label { cursor: pointer; width: 250px; display: block; float: left; }
button, input, select, textarea { font-size: 100%; margin: 0; vertical-align: baseline; *vertical-align: middle; }
```

Comment: When added into a blank HTML page its like 'label input label input' in one line. Maybe add some more HTML structure and the relevant styles to the question to figure out what's going wrong,

Comment: alright, while i was adding the css, I decided to try something.

'input[type="text"], input[type="date"]{ float: left; }'

seemed to fix the problem, but I don't know why. If anyone can explain, that would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, with your updated question it's pretty simple to solve. When you use `float` on an element, it's taken out of the normal positioning of inline elements. This means, that the labels have like a higher priority to be on the left side. That's why you get this output: label, label, input, input. When you also add `float` to the input fields, the original order is restored. Or, when  only using `inline`- or `inline-block`-elements, you can build a lot without the need of floating elements. So in your case, you could also simply change this:

```
label {
    […]
    display: block;
    float:   left;
}
```

to this:

```
label {
    […]
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

alright, while i was adding the css, I decided to try something.

```
input[type="text"], input[type="date"]{ float: left; }
```

seemed to fix the problem, but I don't know why. If anyone can explain, that would be great.

Comment: What you did is exactly what I explained in my answer. You let all elements float to restore the 'expected' order.

Answer (score -1):

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><label for="input1">input1</label></td>
<td><input id="input1" name="input1" type="text" required></td>
<td><label for="input2">input2</label></td>
<td><input id="input2" name="input2" type="date"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'd rather not use tables if I can avoid it. I'll add some css to the original post.